# Go into a page and return a value

Tags: php, web

I would like my code to grab a string included between specific html tags on a website I do not own:

https://website.com/Users/bobby

```
    ...
    <p class="myclass">
    <a href="link.html">634654</a>
    </p>
    ...
```

How would you guys proceed?

Comment: Use an HTML parsing library, like `DOMDocument` or `Simple PHP HTML DOM`.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library--net-11856

Comment: Ok I got the code, but it returns some error messages:                                                       Warning: file_get_contents(https://mywebsite.com/Users/bobby) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in W:\var\www\simple_html_dom.php on line 1097

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in W:\var\www\simple_html_dom.php on line 1129